# Strange string in console from wpdb query

Tags: query, wpdb

I use this code:

```
   $search = $this->wpdb->prepare("WHERE (name LIKE %s OR tag LIKE %s)", '%'. $this->wpdb->esc_like($word) .'%', '%'. $this->wpdb->esc_like($word) .'%');
```

and in console i get:

```
name LIKE '{4b9ad9b602bd32ff99324feebaa1883bb3a3e818f587b35198d4e48093375c78}night{4b9ad9b602bd32ff99324feebaa1883bb3a3e818f587b35198d4e48093375c78}' OR tag LIKE '{4b9ad9b602bd32ff99324feebaa1883bb3a3e818f587b35198d4e48093375c78}night{4b9ad9b602bd32ff99324feebaa1883bb3a3e818f587b35198d4e48093375c78}'
```

how i can remove this strange string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *placeholder escape string* generated by `wpdb::placeholder_escape()` which is used by [`wpdb::add_placeholder_escape()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/add_placeholder_escape/) and which is called by  `wpdb::prepare()`.

So it is safe to keep those escape strings, but there is a `wpdb` method for removing them: [`wpdb::remove_placeholder_escape()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/remove_placeholder_escape/):

```php
// In your case, you'd use $this->wpdb in place of $wpdb.
$query = $wpdb->add_placeholder_escape( 'LIKE %night%' );
$query2 = $wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape( $query );
var_dump( $query, $query2 );
```